# How can I use early stopping with XGBRFRegressor?

Tags: python, xgboost

I've tried fitting a random forest like so:

```
from xgboost import XGBRFRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_regression(random_state=7)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=7)

forest = XGBRFRegressor(num_parallel_tree = 10, num_boost_round = 1000, verbose=3)

forest.fit(
    X_train, 
    y_train,
    eval_set = [(X_test, y_test)],
    early_stopping_rounds = 10,
    verbose = True
)
```

However, early stopping never seems to kick in and as far as I can tell, the model fits the full 10,000 trees requested. The evaluation metric is only printed once, rather than after every boosting round as I would have expected.

What's the right way to set up this type of model (working within the scikit-learn API) so that early stopping takes effect as I would expect?

I have requested clarification from the developers here:

https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/how-is-xgbrfregressor-intended-to-work-with-early-stopping/2391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs say](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/rf.html#standalone-random-forest-with-scikit-learn-like-api):

> [XGBRFRegressor has] default values and meaning of some of the parameters adjusted accordingly. In particular:
>
> - `n_estimators` specifies the size of the forest to be trained; it is converted to `num_parallel_tree`, instead of the number of boosting rounds
> - `learning_rate` is set to 1 by default
> - `colsample_bynode` and `subsample` are set to 0.8 by default
> - `booster` is always `gbtree`

And you can see that in action [in the code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/dfdf0b08fc24e05ad731d4424b8c1a925968779f/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L1459): `num_parallel_trees` gets overridden as the input `n_estimators`, and the `num_boosting_rounds` gets overridden as 1.

It's probably worth reading the paragraphs preceding the documentation link in order to understand how xgboost treats random forests.

Comment: I see now - the docs are accurate, but they do not directly mention `num_boosting_rounds` being overridden. All they say is `In particular, it is impossible to combine random forests with gradient boosting using this API.` which you have to read in conjunction with the corresponding docs for the XGBoost API, which allows higher values of `num_boosting_rounds` for RF + gradient boosting. So in short: no, early stopping cannot be used with XGBRFRegressor.

Comment: The other point of confusion is that `XGBRFRegressor.fit()` accepts all the early stopping parameters, even though they don't really do anything useful.